# ¿Conexión de phpmyadmin en Qt(c++), desde otro servidor?

Tags: c++, phpmyadmin, qt, servidor, wamp

Estoy creando un programa que se conecta a la base de datos de otra computadora, usando Wamppserver y phpmyadmin. El programa me corre bien, tengo la conexión de la siguiente manera:
*.cpp:*

```
    this->db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    this->db.setHostName("192.168.1.xx");
    this->db.setDatabaseName("bd_prueba");
    this->db.setUserName("Jose");
    this->db.setPassword("");
    bool ok = this->db.open();
    return ok;
```

Lo compilo, abro la base de datos, puedo leer y modificar. El problema que tengo es que al momento de correr el programa en el cuadro de: **Application Output**, me aparece este mensaje:

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

He buscado ese error pero nada coincide con lo que yo estoy haciendo, básicamente quiero saber si eso me puede perjudicar en un futuro y como le hago para quitarlo.
Cualquier comentario bienvenido. gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre quitar el error poniendo en el .pro

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
```

y agregue en la carpeta de release las librerias de sql para hacer la conexion.

Answer (score 1):

Ese no es un warning generado por la conección a la base de datos, pienso que estas usando imagenes con exensión .png.

Algunos cambios en la versión 1.6+ de libpng hacen que emita una advertencia o incluso no funcionen correctamente con el perfil original de HP/MS sRGB.

Si quieres eliminarlos, en linux hay una solucion, usa la utilidad `convert`:

```
convert in.png out.png
```

Esta corregira los errores.